# mongodb aggregation $group and then $push a object

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

this is my data :

```
> db.bookmarks.find({"userId" : "56b9b74bf976ab70ff6b9999"}).pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56c2210fee4a33579f4202dd"),
    "userId" : "56b9b74bf976ab70ff6b9999",
    "items" : [
        {
            "itemId" : "28",
            "timestamp" : "2016-02-12T18:07:28Z"
        },
        {
            "itemId" : "29",
            "timestamp" : "2016-02-12T18:07:29Z"
        },
        {
            "itemId" : "30",
            "timestamp" : "2016-02-12T18:07:30Z"
        },
        {
            "itemId" : "31",
            "timestamp" : "2016-02-12T18:07:31Z"
        },
        {
            "itemId" : "32",
            "timestamp" : "2016-02-12T18:07:32Z"
        },
        {
            "itemId" : "33",
            "timestamp" : "2016-02-12T18:07:33Z"
        },
        {
            "itemId" : "34",
            "timestamp" : "2016-02-12T18:07:34Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to have something like (actually i hope the _id can become userId too) :

```
{ 
    "_id" : "56b9b74bf976ab70ff6b9999", 
    "items" : [ 
        { "itemId": "32", "timestamp": "2016-02-12T18:07:32Z" },
        { "itemId": "31", "timestamp": "2016-02-12T18:07:31Z" },
        { "itemId": "30", "timestamp": "2016-02-12T18:07:30Z" }
    ] 
}
```

What I have now :

```
> db.bookmarks.aggregate(
...     { $match: { "userId" : "56b9b74bf976ab70ff6b9999" } },
...     { $unwind: '$items' },
...     { $sort: { 'items.timestamp': -1} },
...     { $skip: 2 },
...     { $limit: 3},
...     { $group: { '_id': '$userId' , items: { $push: '$items.itemId' } } }
... ).pretty()
{ "_id" : "56b9b74bf976ab70ff6b9999", "items" : [ "32", "31", "30" ] }
```

i tried to read the document in mongo and find out i can $push, but somehow i cannot find a way to push such object, which is not defined anywhere in the whole object. I want to have the timestamp also.. but i don't know how should i modified the $group (or others??) to do so. thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code, which I tested in the MongoDB 3.2.1 shell, should give you the output format that you want:

```
> db.bookmarks.aggregate( 
{ "$match" : { "userId" : "Ursula" } }, 
{ "$unwind" : "$items" }, 
{ "$sort" : { "items.timestamp" : -1 } }, 
{ "$skip" : 2 }, 
{ "$limit" : 3 }, 
{ "$group" : { "_id" : "$userId", items: { "$push" :  { "myPlace" : "$items.itemId", "myStamp" : "$items.timestamp" } } } }  ).pretty()
```

Running the above will produce this output:

```
{
    "_id" : "Ursula",
    "items" : [
        {
            "myPlace" : "52",
            "myStamp" : ISODate("2016-02-13T18:07:32Z")
        },
        {
            "myPlace" : "51",
            "myStamp" : ISODate("2016-02-13T18:07:31Z")
        },
        {
            "myPlace" : "50",
            "myStamp" : ISODate("2016-02-13T18:07:30Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

In MongoDB version 3.2.x, you can also use the $out operator in the very last stage of the aggregation pipeline, and have the output of the aggregation query written to a collection. Here is the code I used:

```
> db.bookmarks.aggregate( 
{ "$match" : { "userId" : "Ursula" } }, 
{ "$unwind" : "$items" }, 
{ "$sort" : { "items.timestamp" : -1 } }, 
{ "$skip" : 2 }, 
{ "$limit" : 3 }, 
{ "$group" : { "_id" : "$userId", items: { "$push" :  { "myPlace" : "$items.itemId", "myStamp" : "$items.timestamp" } } } }, 
{ "$out" : "ursula" } )
```

This gives me a collection named "ursula":

```
> show collections
ursula
```

and I can query that collection:

```
> db.ursula.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : "Ursula",
    "items" : [
        {
            "myPlace" : "52",
            "myStamp" : ISODate("2016-02-13T18:07:32Z")
        },
        {
            "myPlace" : "51",
            "myStamp" : ISODate("2016-02-13T18:07:31Z")
        },
        {
            "myPlace" : "50",
            "myStamp" : ISODate("2016-02-13T18:07:30Z")
        }
    ]
}
>
```

Last of all, this is the input document I used in the aggregation query. You can compare this document to how I coded the aggregation query to see how I built the new items array.

```
> db.bookmarks.find( { "userId" : "Ursula" } ).pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56c240ed55f2f6004dc3b25c"),
    "userId" : "Ursula",
    "items" : [
        {
            "itemId" : "48",
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2016-02-13T18:07:28Z")
        },
        {
            "itemId" : "49",
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2016-02-13T18:07:29Z")
        },
        {
            "itemId" : "50",
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2016-02-13T18:07:30Z")
        },
        {
            "itemId" : "51",
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2016-02-13T18:07:31Z")
        },
        {
            "itemId" : "52",
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2016-02-13T18:07:32Z")
        },
        {
            "itemId" : "53",
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2016-02-13T18:07:33Z")
        },
        {
            "itemId" : "54",
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2016-02-13T18:07:34Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: ah i did think this way too... but that's just my wild guess and i am not sure then i give up after one trial, maybe i was missing some bracket or quote...
anyways, you confirm this for me! thanks a lot!!

Comment: after this stage, i find how to act like renaming a field also, using `$project`

`{ $project: { userId: "$_id", items: 1, _id: 0 } }`